# insert in database using php, json and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

i want to insert data to mysql database using php service and json but when i click nothing happens it shows no error no message and the data is not added to the data base help please 
here is the save function

```
function save(){
var eml = document.getElementById("tbemail").value;
var mp = document.getElementById("tbmdp").value;
var data = {email: eml, mdp: mp}

$.ajax({
url:"http://localhost:800/test/insert.php",
type: 'POST',
data: data,
dataType: 'json',
success: function() 
    {alert("success");}
error: function()
    {alert("fail");}
});
}
```

and this my php file insert.php

```
<?php 
$json = $_POST['data'];
$new=json_decode($json, true);

$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to    mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"bd") or die ("no database");   



$sql = "INSERT INTO user (email,mdp) VALUES ($new['email'],$new['mdp'])";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
 echo "created ";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```

Comment: can you show your html code where you create a button or something on which you call save function. And try to find out that all the values coming or not in em mp data?

Comment: i tried to only print the content of eml and mp on the button click and it worked fine im sure the problem is not there

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "data" key in your $_POST array, you have "email" and "mdp", which you can access directly:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$mdp = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['mdp']);
```

There is no json passed in this way, similarly when you have get string, you also don't need to parse it. Turn on error reporting, then you will see that $_POST['data'] is undefined.

BTW, use mysqli_real_escape_string to sanitize the input to prevent from injection.

Comment: yes i tried to send the data in the url and it works fine but i need to send it in json format because this is an example the table that i should realy be working on have 20 columns i cant pass the all in the url
how should i pass the json then plz?

Comment: OK, I don't say you should do it in url. Do it in json as you do, but on the php receiving end it is not json anymore but normal post array, on php end there is no difference how you send it. Try to get those variables like in my answer. You can also check what is in post array by print_r($_POST);

Comment: i did what you said but i still have the same problem nothing happens when i click the button

Comment: I cannot see your html, you need to have some button with onclick="save();" event. If it is submit button, you need to add "return false;". Also make sure you have loaded jquery script before invoking this function.

Comment: yes of course i  did that here is the code
    <a class="button widget uib_w_4 d-margins icon pencil yellow" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="btninscri" onclick="save()">inscription</a>

Comment: add return false! onclick="save(); return false;"

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code seems to be correct, but please try the jQuery AJAX code as follows:

```
 function save(){

      var eml = document.getElementById("tbemail").value;
      var mp = document.getElementById("tbmdp").value;
      var data = {email: eml, mdp: mp}

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:800/test/insert.php",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                error: function () {
                    alert('fail');
                },        
                success: function (data) {                       
                 alert('success');
                }
            });
        }
```

In your data section has to be passed as JSON String, secondly you missed to in include the data `contentType`. Here content type is set as `application/json`, therefore pass the data as JSON string.

Comment: i did what you said and thnx alot at least now it shows the "fail" message any idea why ?

Comment: Dear,Modify the script to show the error message as follows  in error part of ajax script code change it  as               error: function (a,b,c){alert(JSON.stringify(a);JSON.stringify(c); }. and see what error is showing

Comment: i dont realy understand what it shows can you please explain it to me
and its too long to write in a comment ill write it in 2
{"statusText":"OK","status":200,"response":"<br />\n<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>\n<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan=\"5\"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\\wamp\\www\\test\\insert.php on line <i>10</i></th></tr>\n</table></font>\n","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"<br />\n<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>\n<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan=\"5\"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: C:\\wamp\\www\\test\\insert.php on line <i>10</i></th></tr>\n</table></font>\n","upload":{"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null,"UNSENT":0,"OPENED":1,"HEADERS_RECEIVED":2,"LOADING":3,"DONE":4}

Comment: i do believe this is the error right?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\test\insert.php on line 10

Comment: Dear yes its.  No issues with Ajax Script since the status is ,  {"statusText":"OK","status":200,.,..   Narrow down you PHP Code , just comment database code section , simply echo after json_decode.

Comment: yes thats what i thought 2 but then if ajax script status is ok why is he showing the "fail" message wich should only be shown incase of error right?

Comment: here "status":200 means the request is success, , but it always falls to error block , if ther is an error occured in server(php or .NET code. you may check the PHP error shows. once fixed , your code fine

Answer (score 0):

`"Insert.php"` - > Not use for get data  `$json = $_POST['data'];`

Only use this and try

```
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to    mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"bd") or die ("no database");   

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mdp = $_POST['mdp'];

    $new1 = json_encode($email);
    $new2 = json_encode($mdp);

$sql = "INSERT INTO user ('email','mdp') VALUES ('".$new1."','".$new2."')";
$insert = mysqli_query($sql);
if ($insert) {
 echo "created ";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: thnx bro but now i have this error $new1 and $new2 is null 
Error: INSERT INTO user (email,mdp) VALUES (null,null)
Column 'email' cannot be null

Comment: Please use ('".$new1."','".$new2."')

Comment: thnx alot now the php file show no error anymore but its still not working

Comment: the php is showing this 
Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\wamp\www\test\insert.php on line 8
but it adds in the database

Comment: please replace It :- $insert = mysqli_query($sql);
if ($insert) {
 echo "created ";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

Comment: (email,mdp) replace it ('email','mdp')